# IIS 7.5 + Mysql ODBC 3.51 Slows up the website

Tags: mysql, odbc, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I was using IIS 5.1 on Windows XP PC the page used to load in a fraction of second.

Now I have moved to windows server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 and same DB. I checked MySQL, it working in the same way as previous machine. I have checked IIS 7.5 for basic .Net pages not involving DB, even that is working normal.

I think the problem is somewhere else in connection which is making the application dead slow, please suggest how can I increase the speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my DSN, I didnt write IP Address there so it was checking for available hosts and then taking localhost. I have entered the IP Addr of machine in DSN and things are working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's very hard to say without some sort of measuring (profiler, log etc), but you could use managed library to connect to mySQL, I am sure that this would be faster than ODBC

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dotnet.html

**UPDATE for future googlers from Kitiraj comment : **

> The problem was with my DSN, I didnt write IP Address there so it was
>   checking for available hosts and then taking localhost. I have entered
>   the IP Addr of machine in DSN and things are working smooth

Comment: I am using XSD in my web application. Not sure how to connect XSD with managed library, can you please route me to correct place?

Comment: Pleasy clarify and update your question, maybe some one other that me would know, but what has XML Schema to do with database ? How do you connect it with ODBC ?

Comment: I am using a system DSN to connect with the database, I have created a     Dataset for easy access to queries written in XSD(Dataset)

Comment: The problem was with my DSN, I didnt write IP Address there so it was checking for available hosts and then taking localhost. I have entered the IP Addr of machine in DSN and things are working smooth.

Comment: Could you make that comment as an answer, for future googlers with the same problem